# Rails order query by every 6 hours

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, time

I have a query, like so:

```
query = Post.where(is_public: true).order(score: :desc)
```

I want to get the posts that have the highest score per each 6 hour window for when they were `created_at`. How can I accomplish this?

I know that I can accomplish this for ordering by every day, i.e. `query = Post.where(is_public: true).order('DATE(created_at) DESC').order(score: :desc)`

(I'm using Postgres)

Comment: What is that 6 hour window means. Do you have any 4 slots in a day?

Comment: @CharanKumarBorra 4 slots?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code,

```
posts = Post.where('created_at > ?', 6.hours.ago).order(score: :desc)
```

Comment: But then I want to be able to see the next set of posts as well. Should be grouped each 6 hour period